# onclick function not working and not able to pass variable from one page to another

Tags: javascript, php

```
        <?php session_start();
         ?>
        <?php
       include('config.php');
        ?>
           <html>
         <?php include 'header.php'; ?>

        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3  /jquery.min.js"></script>
      <div id="content">

        <h3 class="page-title">Jobseeker Registration</h3>

            <!--<div class="post">-->
                <?php 
                echo $a=$_SESSION['email_check']; ?>

          // This section is form **validation function** which i am calling from button. 

<script LANGUAGE="JavaScript">
   function ValidateForm(form){
     ErrorText= "";
      if (document.frm.f_name.value == "" ) 
       {
       alert ( "Please enter full name" ); 
       document.frm.f_name.focus();
return false;
   }
if ( ( form.gender[0].checked == false ) && ( form.gender[1].checked ==   false ) && ( form.gender[2].checked == false ) ) 

{

alert ( "Please choose your Gender: Male or Female or other" ); 
return false;
}
 var phoneno = /^\d{10}$/;  
if (document.frm.m_number.value == "" ) 
{
alert ( "Please enter valid mobile number" ); 
document.frm.m_number.focus();
return false;
}
else if(!(document.frm.m_number.value.match(phoneno)))
{
alert("Not a valid Phone Number"); 
document.frm.m_number.focus();
 return false;  
}
if (document.frm.edu_ql.selectedIndex == "" ) 
{
alert ( "Please Select Education Qualification" ); 
document.frm.edu_ql.focus(); 
return false;
}
 if (document.frm.address.value == "" ) 
 {

alert ( "Please fill ur complete address" ); 

document.frm.address.focus();
return false;
}

if ( ( document.frm.country.selectedIndex == 0 )) 
{
 alert ( "Please Select Country" ); 
 return false;
 }
 if ( ( document.frm.state.selectedIndex == 0 )) 
 {
 alert ( "Please Select state" ); 
 return false;
  }
 if ( ( document.frm.city.selectedIndex == 0 )) 
 {
 alert ( "Please Select city" ); 
  return false;
 }
 var regPostcode = /^([1-9])([0-9]){5}$/;
if (document.frm.pin.value == "" ) 
 {
 alert ( "Please enter valid postal code" ); 
  document.frm.pin.focus();
  return false;
  }
  else if(!(document.frm.pin.value.match(regPostcode)))
  {
  alert("Not a postal code"); 
  document.frm.pin.focus(); 
  return false;  
   }
  var mailformat = /^\w+([\.-]?\w+)*@\w+([\.-]?\w+)*(\.\w{2,3})+$/; 
  if (document.frm.empl_emailid.value == "" ) 
  {
  alert ( "Please enter valid emailid" );
  document.frm.empl_emailid.focus(); 
   return false;
   }
   else if(!(document.frm.empl_emailid.value.match( mailformat)))
  {
   alert("Not a valid Email id"); 
   document.frm.empl_emailid.focus();  
   return false;  
     }
     if (document.frm.pass.value == "" ) 
    {
    alert ( "Please fill ur password" ); 
    document.frm.pass.focus(); 
    return false;
     }
    if (document.frm.ppwd.value == "" ) 
    {
    alert ( "Please fill confirm password" ); 
      document.frm.ppwd.focus(); 
    return false;
    }
     if(document.frm.pass.value != document.frm.ppwd.value)
    {
     alert ( "Please match password" );
    document.frm.ppwd.focus();  
      return false;
      }
      else
    {
    return true;
    }
     if (ErrorText= "") { form.submit() }
      }
       <!-- random number -->
      function getRandomString($length = 10) {
      $validCharacters = “abcdefghijklmnopqrstuxyvwz1234567890+-*#&@!?”;
      $validCharNumber = strlen($validCharacters);
      $result = “”;
     for ($i = 0; $i < $length; $i++) {
     $index = mt_rand(0, $validCharNumber – 1);
      $result .= $validCharacters[$index];
      }
       echo $result;
        return $result;
      }
    $result = getRandomString();

     <!-- Random ends -->

       </script>    

        // now my form section started where i will call the function.

       <form action="process_referral_register.php"  method="post"  enctype="multipart/form-data" name="frm" id="frm" style="border:none; margin:0">

      <div class="col-md-6">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label>Full name</label>
      <input type="text" name="f_name" class="form-control" required></div>
        </html>
       <input type="button" class="btn btn-denger"  onClick="window.location.href='index.php'" value="cancel">  
        <input class="btn btn-success" type="submit"  name="employee"  value="submit &rarr;" onClick="return ValidateForm(this.form);getrandomstring(); "></div>
```

My form has started and more form fields at the end i am calling submit button and **onclick** event. but on click event not working for both functions.** please help. My form has many fields which i have not mentioned here. please help.

Comment: Did you check console error in browser?

Comment: cursor is not going to function.